# Change text into <span> with jquery comand

Tags: jquery, class, drop-down-menu, selector

I need to change text into a span.

I'm looking for this because I have a drop-down menu, I use a jQuery selector option but this does not change the text, select only from the options.

I need to change "seleziona" with other text.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, post the ("*[mcve]*") code itself. Also, what "*jQuery selector option*" have you used? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong with your attempts? What did you expect the code to do, what did it do instead?

Comment: i use this : var theText = "";

$("# option").each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == theText) {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
  }
});

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do a change event
2. Then trigger it

1.

```
$("#span1").on('change',function(){
 //Do calculation and change value of other span here
 $("#span2").text('calculated value');});
```

2.

```
$("#span1").text('test').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Srebnywilkun is correct. This answer only provides a short notation.

```
$("#span1").on('change',function(){
    $("#span2").text('calculated value');
}).change(); // defining this at the end of the function would automatically trigger the change event after the event is registered.
```